# Ubuntu software searching very slow ubuntu 21.04

Tags: software-installation, search, download-manager, ubuntu-store

I don't know why but every time I search for something in ubuntu software it takes forever to load but note its not my wifi fault I have a very fast 100mbp wifi connection and my laptop is not that old its medium end with 4Gb and i3 processor I don't know why it happens even I search something common like vscode it just keeps loading I don't know why. If you know the answer please consider let me know the answer too.

Comment: I often find the software store does not load or does not return search results (as you describe). I usually issue a `killall snap-store` in a terminal and then re-start. 100% always "fixes" the problem for me. I usually kill it afterwards too as for whatever reason it remains resident in memory and uses up LOADS of memory.